# SonarQube 5.3: Configure number of lines of source code displayed in Component Viewer

Tags: java, configuration, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

How to configure the **maximum number of lines of source code** shown in the *Component Viewer* in SonarQube? I must be blind but I cannot find it either in SonarQube itself or on Internet.

[Component Viewer](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Component+Viewer) is the heart of SonarQube: it displays the source code of a file, and its high-level statistics. However, it displays maximum of 1000 lines of source code, then there is a spinning wheel under the last line and I cannot see the rest of the source code.

[image]

N.B. I am using SonarQube 5.3.

Comment: it's just a network latency, the spinning wheel would disappear and show the next 1000 lines, alternatively you can go on the action menu (right top corner of the view) and go for Show Raw Source which will open a pop-up with the full source code. However I couldn't find any configurability of the n lines of code to show at max

Comment: @A.DiMatteo: 1. The wheel unfortunately never stops. I am running *local* SonarQube server, so network latency is not the culprit. 2. Show Raw Source is no added value - I *have* the source code in Eclipse! What I need is to see *both* the Sonar issues *and* the source code at the same time. 3. I couldn't find any configurability either :(

Comment: What version of sonarqube are you using? My installation is remote and I didn't have this issue, the spinning ended after less than 2 seconds

Comment: @A.DiMatteo: SonarQube 5.3. And AdBlock Plus totally deactivated for localhost. And checked with FF, Chrome, IE 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you cannot see more than 1000 lines is a bug in SonarQube 5.3, reported [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/1000$20lines/sonarqube/mu-9J46i1BE/IIoCDgQLEQAJ). It is fixed (by [this commit](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/commit/de88db0d9ee0df1ee1f79de4a090151ba2f2f1f5) I guess) in SonarQube 5.4.

The number of lines shown by default in the Component Viewer is not configurable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me lot of time with more searching!